# Go - get server address from kubeconfig file

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

Basically, my kubeconfig file has:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
 - cluster:
      server: <OAM ip address> this is what I want
(...)
```

I want to get the server address.
Previously searching , I've found this solution:

```
config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
// creates the clientset
clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

nodes, err := clientset.CoreV1().Nodes().List(metav1.ListOptions{})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
nodeip := []corev1.NodeAddress{}
for i := 0; i < len(nodes.Items); i++ {
    nodeip = nodes.Items[i].Status.Addresses
    fmt.Println(nodeip[0].Address)
}
fmt.Println(nodes.Items[0].Status.Addresses)
```

But it gives me the Internal IP, not the OAM server IP (which is inside the Kubernetes config file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the server address from the `kubeconfig` file, just read it from your `config` variable:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"

    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/homedir"
)

func main() {
    var kubeconfig *string

    if home := homedir.HomeDir(); home != "" {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    } else {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    }

    flag.Parse()

    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("server: %s\n", config.Host)
}
```

---

If you're curious what other fields are available on the `rest.Config` object, a quick solution is to print out the `config` variable using the `%+v` format specifier:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", config)
```

For more details, look at the [reference documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/rest#Config).

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
A newbie question, how am I able to check which options the "config" variable has?
I mean, config.Host is one of them, what are the others? Is there a place in the documentation where I can check it?

Comment: I've updated the question to address your comment.